# graphql passing dynamic data to mutation

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo-server

haven't used `graphql` or `mongodb` previously. What is the proper way to pass objects for the update mutation?

Since the only other way i see to pass multiple dynamically appearing parameters is to use `input` type which is appears to be a bit ineffective to me (in terms of how it looks in the code, especially with bigger objects), i just pass the possible values themselves. however in this case i need to dynamically construct `updateObject`, which again, going to get messy for the bigger models.

for example now i did:

```
Mutation: {
        updateHub: async (_, { id, url, ports, enabled }) => {
            const query = {'_id': id};
            const updateFields = {
                ...(url? {url: url} : null),
                ...(ports? {ports: ports} : null),
                ...(enabled? {enabled: enabled} : null)
            };
            const result = await HubStore.findByIdAndUpdate(query, updateFields);
            return {
                success: !result ? false : true,
                message: 'updated',
                hub: result
            };
        }
}
```

any advise on the better way to handle this?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears your code could benefit from using ES6 spread syntax -- it would permit you to deal with an arbitrary number of properties from your `args` object without the need for serial tertiary statements.

```
Mutation: {
        updateHub: async (_, { id, ...restArgs } ) => {
            const query = {'_id': id};
            const updateFields = { ...restArgs };
            const result = await HubStore.findByIdAndUpdate(query, updateFields);
            return {
                success: !result ? false : true,
                message: 'updated',
                hub: result
            };
        }
}
```

If for some reason you need to explicitly set the undefined properties to `null` in your object, you could possibly use some a config obj and method like `defaults` from the lodash library as shown below:

```
import { defaults } from 'lodash';
const nullFill = { url: null, ports: null, enabled: null }; // include any other properties that may be needed

Mutation: {
        updateHub: async (_, { id, ...restArgs } ) => {
            const query = {'_id': id};
            const updateFields = defaults(restArgs, nullFill);
            const result = await HubStore.findByIdAndUpdate(query, updateFields);
            return {
                success: !result ? false : true,
                message: 'updated',
                hub: result
            };
        }
}
```

Also, FWIW, I would consider placing the dynamic arguments that could be potentially be updated on its own input type, such as `HubInput` in this case, as suggested in the [graphql docs](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/mutations-and-input-types/). Below I've shown how this might work with your mutation. Note that because nothing on HubInput is flagged as requird (`!`) you are able to pass a dynamic collection of properties to update. Also note that if you take this appraoch you will need to properly destructure your `args` object initially in your mutation, something like `{ id, input }`.

```
    input HubInput {
       url: String
       ports: // whatever this type is, like [String]
       enabled: Boolean
       // ...Anything else that might need updating
     }

     type UpdateHubPayload {
        success: Boolean
        message: String
        hub: Hub // assumes you have defined a type Hub
     }

     updateHub(id: Int, input: HubInput!): UpdateHubPayload
```

Comment: thanks for such detailed response! i guess i missed that the spread operator can be used in such way, cool! could u please elaborate on possible implementation of the separate type for the dynamic arguments? i guess that'll be useful not only for me.

Comment: @user1935987 I've added to and refined my answer above in response to your request - hope this helps.

Comment: ahh ok, you mean to use the `input` graphql type. probably misunderstood you. yeah, that is a possible solution, however personally don't want to use it since it'll add a lot more code, especially for the larger objects.